# How to quit ChromeDriver after Invalid Argument Exception

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Here is my current code:

```
options.addArguments("--user-data-dir=Profile");
try {
  driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
}
catch (Exception org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException) {
  driver.quit
}
```

InvalidArgumentException isn't throwing until the browser window has already opened, if I try quit this in the catch block it obviously prints a nullpointer exception because the driver is never fully initialised. How can I handle an InvalidArgumentException such as the user data dir being in-use whilst also closing the chromedriver window that has already opened.

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;   
import org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException;

    WebDriver driver;
    Boolean success;
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

    try {
    options.addArguments("--user-data-dir=Profile");
    success = true;
    }
    catch (InvalidArgumentException invArgEx) {
    success = false;
    }

    if (success) {
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    }
```